# math results as node text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use a math formula as node text. I searched a little bit, some suggestion is using fpu library to avoid dimension too big error, below code not work, expect node text is \x/1000, so should be 16.544.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\x{16544}
    \node {\x/100};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to instruct the actual calculation. Do `\pgfmathprint{\x/100}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The macro `\pgfmathprint` works with for example `1654/100` but for `16544/100` it gives an error `Dimension too large`.

Comment: @matexmatics I'll get `165.439000000000`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathprint{16544/100}
\end{document}`
results in a pdf containing 163.84 but gives an error Dimension too large with TeX Live 2022 and TeX Live 2023.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\fpeval` can be used. The package [xfp](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp) is loaded but this isn't necessary from 2022-06-01 release of LaTeX: see https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}%not necessary from 2022-06-01: see https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\x{16544}
    \node {\fpeval{\x/100}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, how can I keep 1 digitals only? by default it's 2 digitals there!

Comment: @lucky1928 Rounding can be achieved with `\fpeval{round(\x/100,1)}`.